# Set Session attribute using expression language

Tags: jsp, session, attributes, el

How I can set an attribute in a session using expression language in the following code

```
 <body>
        <h1>Hello ${param.name}!</h1>
        <% String n = $ {param.name} %>

        <%
            session.setAttribute("user", n);
        %>  

        <a href="process.jsp">visit</a>  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using the following code you can set values to the session variable:

```
<c:set var="user" value="${param.name}" scope="session" />
```

To print the session variable:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user}" />
```